# how to save single form data to multipe different table based on button click in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`invoice` table stores current form data submitted by user. i want to add two button on form one save to `invoices` table other to `invoices_temp` table on same form.

```
  <%= form_with(model: @invoice, :html => {:id => 'invoice-form-validation'}, url: [@payment_milestone,@invoice], local: true) do |form| %>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="field columns large-3">
        <%= form.label :invoice_generated_for,:class=>"required" %>
        <%= form.select :invoice_generated_for, [['Tax Invoice', 1], ['Pro forma Invoice', 0]], :prompt => 'Select One' %>
      </div>

      <div class="field columns large-3">
        <%= form.label :invoice_type,:class=>"required" %>
        <%= form.select :invoice_type, [['services', 1], ['milestones', 2]], :prompt => 'Select One' %>
      </div>
      <%= form.hidden_field :payment_milestone_id, value: @payment_milestone.id%>

      <div class="field columns large-3 invoice_from_date">
        <%= form.label :from_date,:class=>"required" %>
        <%= form.text_field :from_date, class: 'datepicker', readonly: 'true' %>
      </div>

      <div class="field columns large-3 invoice_to_date">
        <%= form.label :to_date,:class=>"required" %>
        <%= form.text_field :to_date, class: 'datepicker', readonly: 'true' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions text-center">
      <%= form.submit :class=>"button primary button-margin-top"%>
    </div>

    <div class="actions text-center">
      <%= form.submit 'temp_submit_button', :class=>"button primary button-margin-top"%>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

invoices_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_financial_payment_milestone_invoices_path, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to project_financial_payment_milestone_invoices_path}
        format.json { render json: @invoice.projecterrors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Take a look at the params when you click the different buttons and see how they differ. That will be your first clue... check [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit#986-About-the-options-argument) out, too.

Comment: Give different name for each buttons , then when submitted check in controller action which button is triggered and apply the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use different action for each post. But for it, you wil need to write some part of js code

But you can use different name for different submit buttons. For example

```
<%= form_with...do |form| %>
...
  <%= form.submit 'Submit Invoice', name: 'invoice_submit' %>
  <%= form.submit 'Submit Temp Invoice', name: 'temp_invoice_submit' %>
...
<% end %>
```

Inside your controller you can check which button was clicked and handle it. For example:

```
  def create
    invoice_model = params[:invoice_submit] ? Invoice : InvoicesTemp
    @invoice = invoice_model.new(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
...
```

You should know it is only example(not good solution). I think, will be better to use another approach for it. Like 'Regular invoice' and 'Temporary invoice' radio buttons on the form instead of different buttons. You can use one table for save it, but manage it through different models(STI). All depends on situations and how mach different the behavior of them.